# Getting and setting window position on the windows command shell?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm looking for a way to get and set the position and size of a window from the command shell.

I was however only able to find how to do it using PowerShell:

```
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Window {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
}
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
"@

$Handle = (Get-Process -Id $Args[0]).MainWindowHandle
$WindowRect = New-Object RECT
$GotWindowRect = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle, [ref]$WindowRect)
ConvertTo-Json($WindowRect)
```

Is there an equivalent that does this in the (non-powershell) command line?

Comment: Not likely. You could squeeze everything on a very long one-line _PowerShell_ Command-Line, but I really do not see the point in doing that.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm looking for a non-powershell solution though. I'll clarify that. Thanks anyway, I was afraid of it not being possible too :(

Comment: If you're looking for a _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Command-Line PreProcessor Solution, then I guess that you are just aiming too high, @The Oddler. As its Name states, the `Cmd.Exe` Executable Binary File has been intended just for that, for Short Commands being launched on a single Line.

Maybe you can go toward the _Python_ Dynamic Programming Language and try your luck. There are even _Python_ Modules that are emulating entire Web-Browsers, so - who knows? I still doubt that you will be able to perform all of the Monkey Tricks from a Single (maybe SemiColon-Separated) Command-Line.